# split lists from library(rgbif) function occ_data into data frame

Tags: r, list, dataframe

```
library(rgbif)
library(dplyr)
```

#### data and script

```
splist<-c("Acantholyda serbica",
          "Acromyrmex lobicornis",
          "Anthostomella pedemontana",
          "Anthostomella sabinianae",
          "Aphelenchoides stammeri",
          "Aphrophora saratogensis")

keys <- sapply(splist, function(x) name_suggest(x)$key[1], USE.NAMES=T)

mydata<-occ_data(taxonKey=keys, hasCoordinate=TRUE, return="data")
```

#### Here comes the problem

mydata is now a list containing several lists and one data frame called data

i need to combine all the data frames called data from all the different species in one single data frame

I added return="data" to occ_data witch simplifies the return to only what I was looking for. However, now the problem is binding data frames of different sizes..

This loop prints the data frames nicely

```
  for (i in seq(data)){
   print(data[[i]])
   }
```

this does not work, but shows what i am attempting

```
 for (i in seq(data)){
 select(data[[i]], name, decimalLatitude, decimalLongitude) %>%
 bind_rows()
  }
```

I need to rbind several of these

```
  cbind(c(data[[2]]$name), 
    c(data[[2]]$decimalLatitude),
    c(data[[2]]$decimalLongitude))
```

I am doing this for hundreds of species, so any suggestions would be appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer to my question in this blog post:

https://discuss.ropensci.org/t/some-thoughts-on-working-with-rgbif-occurrence-data-including-mapping/1105 (thank you sckott)

problem solved by using rbindlist from library(data.table) and lapply

```
df<- rbindlist(lapply(data, function(x) x$data), fill = TRUE, use.names = TRUE)
```

and from here im able to select

```
dplyr::select(df, name, decimalLatitude, decimalLongitude)
```